# Sleep function in XSL

Tags: php, xml, xslt, twitter, saxon

I think there is no direct way to do this in XSL but wanted to check with you all before writing a server-side code.

I'm working on a website to display tweets from hundreds of different accounts using twitter API.
There is a large XML file containing 200+ twitter ID's and count (1-12). I have a PHP script that does OAuth and outputs JSON using the twitter API. This PHP file takes both id and count as query strings.
Now twitter does have a limit to the number of requests that can be sent per 15 minutes. Since the web page is generated using XSL transformation via Saxon, I was thinking to do something like-

```
  <xsl:template name="all-social">

    <xsl:for-each select="/social/twitter">
      <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text(concat('http://something/twitter.php?
    id=',@id,'&amp;count=',@count))"/> 
       <!-- or apply-templates select="document(--URL--)" -->
    </xsl:for-each> 

  </xsl:template>
```

This will return the JSON of tweets and I can do everything on the front-end to display it properly. But to overcome the API limit I need to add a pause or sleep inside the `for-each` loop like-

```
      <xsl:template name="all-social">

        <xsl:for-each select="/social/twitter">

           <!-- Wait for 5 seconds -->

          <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text(concat('http://something/twitter.php?
        id=',@id,'&amp;count=',@count))"/>
        </xsl:for-each> 

      </xsl:template>
```

Again, I understand this is very easy to do by just using the server-side scripting, by I'm curious if there is a way to add a sleep() during XSL transformation. Any ideas/recommendation will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You are conflating XSLT with procedural programming languages. The `for-each` in XSLT is not a "loop" and the output of an XSLT has no use until the whole XSLT completes. So even if you could do what you are trying to do, it would not be advisable.

Comment: Why a sleep during the transformation, and not simply _before_ it, that is, in between transformations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this: one is to execute the transformation periodically on the server (i.e. sleep between transformations), the other is to generate HTML code containing Javascript (or Saxon-CE) code that periodically fetches the twitter feed. We demonstrated how to do the latter in a paper at XML Prague 2013.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know XSLT has no native sleep functionality, but you can use an extension function. E.g. in case you're processing with java, you can use [Xalan-J](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html#ext-elements) to call Thread.sleep.

For reference: found on [https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014105302), maybe meanwhile there are better extension libraries as this recommendation is from 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Late reply. This works for me with SaxonPE on the desktop. I don't know if it will translate to your environment. 4 second pause:

```
<xsl:template name="sleep" xmlns:thread="java.lang.Thread">
    <xsl:value-of select="thread:sleep(4000)"/>        
</xsl:template>
```

**Amplifying info**: It worked very well for me when running inside OxygenXML with SaxonPE selected. However, I have *not* gotten it to work when running transforms from the command line.

I think in Oxygen, the transform found the java.package in the internal Oxygen runtime. I haven't figured out how to make the thread package available at the command line.